# Crystal Reports: If/Else formula giving wrong results

Tags: t-sql, crystal-reports, db2

I am writing a Crystal report with 2 separate queries - one using DB2 database and one using a SQL database.  I linked the queries together using a field, though I did have to convert the data type on one so it could be linked (not sure if this is relevant).

The DB2 query is giving me all of my customer data displayed on the report, including a customer ID.  The only thing I'm pulling from the SQL DB is the same customer ID, just from another table.  If the customer ID from the DB2 query is found in the customer ID list from SQL, I do not want to display that customer record.

First, I created a formula called "CustID" like this:

```
if {Command.Customer_ID} = {Command1.Customer_ID} then "True" else "False"
```

I then wrote a Record for Select Expert like this:

```
{@CustID} = "False"
```

This is giving me no records returned at all.  I feel like I have a lapse in my logic somewhere but I can figure out where.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(not sure if this is relevant)` - it might be.  What are the types?  For troubleshooting purposes, what happens if you disable the filter - do you get any rows at all, and what about the data in the derived column?

Comment: The field is all numbers, but the data type in one DB was varchar and the data type in the second DB was int.  I just converted the varchar to int first, but when that didn't work, I tried it the other way around - still the same results.